# Model architecture without ORM or Framework for API

Tags: php, mysql, api

Let me first say that I realize this question is *vague* and does not have a *single* answer. Nonetheless, I would greatly appreciate the insight of the StackOverflow community. To the purpose of this site, an answer will be chosen based on adherence to the specification and its address of roadblocks.

#### Overview

I am starting a project that will largely be a RESTful API, currently with about a half dozen *models*. However, their will also be a website. The goal is loosely to follow an MVC architecture so that the site and API utilize the same codebase. My plan is to heavily utilize Models, and light (or not at all) on Controllers. The views will vary between JSON (API) and HTML (website).

#### Specification

- *No ORM*. I'm married to MySQL + PHP at the moment. While this may change later, I'm comfortable committing to the two and therefore don't need an ORM.
- *Balanced Abstraction*. I do believe in *Fat Models*. However, per the above, I don't need queries written for me. Nonetheless, I still want to encapsulate the model properties.
- *Speed*. As the site will largely utilize the API, speed is a cornerstone. With respect, I'd rather avoid the weight of a full-stack framework.

#### Roadblocks

- If models are custom classes, what would be the best way to load multiple. I'd prefer to lazy load, but not at the expense of performance. Without *pre-optimizing*, what would be a clean approach for loading multiple models without the a half dozed `require()` statements at the top of every page.
- Balancing abstraction, I don't want to create `getX()` methods in each Model for every possible query. Yet, I would like to avoid writing queries in my views. So how can I cleanly balance this between abstraction and still respect MVC paradigm?

If something exists that focuses on Model abstraction, which it probably does, please point me in that direction. However, I am familiar with CakePHP, Frapi, Code Ignitor and have read up on Doctrine. I believe these don't meet the specification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out Eric Evans' [Domain-Driven Design](http://domaindrivendesign.org/), or the free online redux [Domain-Driven Design Quickly](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/domain-driven-design-quickly).

Specification

- You don't need to use an ORM if you don't want to.  Or you can use an ORM sometimes, or custom SQL other times as needed.  Whatever code you write within those methods to query a database is an implementation detail and should be abstracted by the public-facing interface of the Model class.
- You should write Model methods to encapsulate logical operations pertaining to your application.  That is, your classes and methods are based on higher-level business requirements, not as low-level CRUD operations.
- There's no need to have a Framework with a capital F to utilize Models.  Check out the [Page Controller](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/pageController.html) pattern, which IMHO fits the PHP convention better than the Front Controller pattern that is so common among frameworks.

Roadblocks

- Regarding lazy-loading, try the [autoloading](http://php.net/autoload) feature of PHP.
- Avoid tedious getters and setters by designing your Model classes to higher-level interfaces, according to business goals, not low-level CRUD.  A Model method could return a PHP hash array of other Model object instances.  For simple object fields, you could simply make object member variables public.

Comment: +1 for being the lone ranger. I'll review these links. Quick question, what's up with *Framework with a capital F*?

Comment: I was just trying to be funny.  I mean a "heavy" framework that requires you to "do it their way" and conform to a bunch of conventions.  You said you wanted to avoid a full-stack framework.